# Hive reads file incorrectly

Tags: hive

I have created an external hive table with pipe delimiters. All my columns are of type Strings. One of the values in the file is a paragraph of text. What I cannot understand is why Hive terminates this text and puts it in the next column when there isn't a pipe there. There are lots of consecutive whitespaces in that paragraph. Could this be a problem when Hive tries to read the file. Example text is:

```
'...SATA            Hooper Size  \= 6000...'.
```

Hive puts the part till SATA in columnA and the next part in columnB. It repeats this I think whenver the whitespaces are too long. Any clue as to why it does that and how to work around this problem? Is it something like if there are lots of consecutive whitespaces, Hive thinks that the string has ended?

Comment: if you put a pipe symbol in between SATA and Hooper, is it actually splitting at that point??

Comment: @sonic I tried to do as you asked by copying a row in a notepad(file.txt) and edited a file and put a pipe between them and save it with UTF-8 encoding. I created another table and loaded this file.  But Hive throws an exception saying 'Not a valid file'. The original file is an output of a map reduce job.

Comment: how are you adding the pipe symbol in hadoop output? in the reducer?

Comment: also make sure you created table properly by specifying '|' as delimiter

Comment: In the mapper. Output is fine. I could check it easily since its in text format. The problem is Hive is not able to read it correctly

Comment: I guess , you have some invisible characters there causing to new line

Comment: I don't think so, I can't see them in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had similar problem becaus of invisible character.

1.Download data to local.

2.Either you should have pipe delimiter or you have a new line character there .

to confirm that,open the file in VI and check the (invisible) characters.

Comment: I just did this and checked it in gVim and Notepad++ and no, there are no hidden pipes between these words.

Comment: What is even more bizzare is: Suppose there is Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4, Col5. Hive puts part till SATA in Col1 then 'Hooper Size  \= 6000' in Col3. (Yes, Col2 is blank) then puts next word say 'Code H \= 40' in Col5. I have no idea why.

Comment: Isn't Vim equivalent of Vi. http://superuser.com/questions/50833/is-there-a-vi-equivalent-i-can-use-on-windows-xp-and-later

Comment: u said gvim in last comment that is the reason why i refered vi,I dont know about gvim also.